# API Managment setting policy giving error Backend with id 'servicefabric' could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to set the policy for service fabric but I get the following error

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: Error in element
>   'set-backend-service' on line 16, column 10: Backend with id
>   'servicefabric' could not be found.

Where do i set the backend id

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service backend-id="servicefabric" sf-service-instance-name="fabric:/Medivet.MicroServices/Medivet.WebApi" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still no UI to manage backends. Will have to use API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/backend